# How can I access a variable declared in a Trait

Tags: scala, traits

I have declared an Array inside a Trait. I can use functions declared inside traits fine if I extend my classes with them using extends or with. However, if I declare a variable, I can't access it. So, question is how can you access variables defined in a trait from a class?

Example:

```
trait X {
    val a = Array(100, 200, 300)
    ....
    def geta(): Array[Int] = this.a
    ....
}

object Y extends X {
    ....
    val x = a // Compiler error: Can't access a
    val y = geta() // This is fine
    ....
}
```

Comment: Could you add some sample code please?

Comment: This code compiles fine for me. Have you over-simplified your MCVE? Is `a` definitely not declared as `private` or something like that?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I was just making a spelling mistake. It works indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I get what you're asking...

As you've found, one way to access trait functions inside a class is to extend that trait. This also applies to variables:

```
trait TestTrait {
  val x = "I'm x"
}

class TestClass extends TestTrait {
  def printStuff = {
    println(x)
  }
}

new TestClass().printStuff // >>> I'm x
```

Obviously if you have any functions/variables you've not assigned to a value inside that trait, you will need to assign them to values inside the class (same goes with functions):

```
trait TestTrait {
  val x = "I'm x"
  val y: String
}

class TestClass extends TestTrait {
  override val y = "I'm y"

  def printStuff = {
    println(x, y)
  }
}

new TestClass().printStuff // >>> (I'm x,I'm y)
```